# Too few arguments to function directory::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Hei I'm making a controller to get current id from another table and need help doing so, because I get some error on it

> Too few arguments to function /directory/::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

This is my function store controller

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'A' => 'required|max:200',
        'B' => 'required|max:800'
    ));
    $try = new Me();
    $try->id_tableA = Auth::id();
    //$id = 1;
    $incase = Incase::find($id);
    $try->id_tableB = $incase->id;
    $try->A = $request->A;
    $try->B = $request->B;

    $try->save();

    return redirect()->route('controller.index');
}
```

So I can insert to my table with own initialize value when I write `$id = 1`
but when I find id and create parameter use $id on the function parameter it turn error like what I said in header, Can you help me guys so glad if this problem can fix very soon

Comment: The error is not inside yout method, but it happens when you call the method (you only give 1 argument instead of $request and $id).
Can you show us the place in your code where you call `::store` ?

Comment: I call it on my form
<form action="{{ route('controller.store')}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="store_form">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Chay22 I got some idea when you told me in previous answer,

so I edit my form, Controller and route on my laravel

```
Route::post('directory/{incase}','ControllerController@store')->name('controller.store');
```

on my form I pass the 2nd parameter in the route

```
{{ route('controller.store',$incase->id) }}
```

on my Controller I change my Id to $incase

```
public function store(Request $request, $incase)
```

on my route I make post route to retrieve the id to db

```
Route::post('directory/{incase}','ControllerController@store')->name('controller.store');
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
```

and,

```
public function store(Request $request, $id = 1)
```

is the former, has no default value (required) while the latter has one which is `1` (optional). Obvious, right?

So whenever you're trying to call the belonging route with the first example of controller method with `route('controller.store')`. It will raise an error, because there is no parameter passed. The conclusion is to pass the ID when you call it, for example `route('controller.store', [1])`

Or if you design it to behave an optional ID to be passed, you're doing right then.

As a matter of preference, I rewrite your code a bit

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $incase = Incase::findOrFail($id);
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'A' => 'required|max:200',
        'B' => 'required|max:800'
    ));

    $try = new Me();
    $try->id_tableA = Auth::id();
    $try->id_tableB = $incase->id;
    $try->A = $request->A;
    $try->B = $request->B;

    $try->save();

    return redirect()->route('controller.index');
}
```

I check the `Incase` first for the ID given from route whether it does exist or not, then throw (show) a 404 response if there is no ID found.

Comment: So From what you told me I change my code but still got an error on it
I get the id when I call it with this code

{{ route('controllers.store',$incase->id) }}

and change my function parameter to

public function store(Request $request, $incase){
......
}

but still got error Too few arguments to function /directory/::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected